# pass remoteUser value in HttpServletRequest to mockmvc perform test

Tags: spring, mockito, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have an api call as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/course", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<Object> getCourse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throwsException {
        User user = userDao.getByUsername(request.getRemoteUser());

}
```

I'm getting the user null when I call this from the test class like:

```
HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
 Mockito.when(request.getRemoteUser()).thenReturn("test1");

    MvcResult result =  mockMvc.perform( get( "/course")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .andExpect( status().isOk() )
                    .andExpect( content().contentType( "application/json;charset=UTF-8" ) )
                    .andReturn();
```

When I debug request object I can see `remoteUser=null`. So how can I pass the value to remote user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`RequestPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/RequestPostProcessor.html) in order to modify the `MockHttpServletRequest` in any fashion you want. In your case:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/course").with(request -> {
                    request.setRemoteUser("USER");
                    return request;
                })...
```

And if you're stuck with older versions of Java:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/course").with(new RequestPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public MockHttpServletRequest postProcessRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request) {
                request.setRemoteUser("USER");
                return request;
            }
        })...
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin to set `remoteUser` in the `MockHttpServletRequest` use the `@WithMockUser` annotation.

1. Add the dependency `testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.0.4.RELEASE")` in `build.gradle.kts`
2. Add the `@WithMockUser(username = "user")` in the test

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [DossierController::class])
internal class DossierControllerTest {
  
  @MockkBean
  lateinit var request: MockHttpServletRequest
  
  @Test
  @WithMockUser(username = "user")
  fun createDossierTest() {

  }
}
```