# HttpServletRequest to MultipartHttpServletRequest: ClassCastException in Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, classcastexception

I am trying to write Junit tests for a Controller class which contains the following method.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/mappingUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFileMethod(HttpServletResponse httpResponse, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, ModelMap model) throws Exception {

  try {
    MultipartFile multipartFile = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) httpRequest).getFile("fileName");
   }
  catch(Exception e){}
}
```

In the test class I have the following method

```
 @Test
public void testUploadFileMethod() throws Exception {
mockMVC.perform(post("/mappingUrl")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

I am getting the the below exception when the test is executed:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest
```

Is there a way I can test the method without changing the existing code? The class is used through out the application and I am afraid I might break something else.

I went through questions that were similar and the following are the ones that came close:

[Mockito ClassCastException - A mock cannot be cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462611/mockito-classcastexception-a-mock-cannot-be-cast)

[pass remoteUser value in HttpServletRequest to mockmvc perform test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162679/pass-remoteuser-value-in-httpservletrequest-to-mockmvc-perform-test?rq=1)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request

Comment: Depending on the Spring Version use `multipart` (for Spring 5) else use `fileUpload` as a factory method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try

```
MockMultipartFile myFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "myFile.txt", "text/plain", "myFileContent".getBytes());
mockMVC.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/mappingUrl")
                    .file(myFile)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request)

Comment: It says   `The method multipart(String) is undefined for the type MockMvcRequestBuilders`

Comment: Ah got it..sorry I skipped the first line of the linked answer.                         **Since MockMvcRequestBuilders#fileUpload is deprecated**.                             I am acutally using an older version of java and `mockMVC.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/mappingUrl")
                    .file(myFile)).andExpect(status().isOk());` worked for me.